# node.js retrieve html from external server remove everything under <center> tag in retrieved html and pipe to client

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

The following code retrieves and pipes html from a third party server to a client application, which works on node.js, express.js and with the request package installed.

```
app.get('/Redirect', function(req, res) {
        var url = 'https://www.example.com/sample.html'
        res.contentType("application/html");
        req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

Not asking to debug the above. It works and it retrieves the html and pipes the html to the client application on the browser when run on node.js. But need help with jquery inside the pipe.  Client application just calls [www.clientwebsiteexample.com/request](http://www.clientwebsiteexample.com/request) and the code returns the sample.html for further processing using js.

To be solved on the server side:
Strip everything under `<center> </center>` tags in the retrieved html including all child content and the `<center> </center>` tags before the piping out the res to to the client browser. The page has multiple `<center> </center>` tags. The rest of the html tags should remain intact.

On a normal webpage, could try something like,
`$('<center>').html(url).children().remove().end().html();`
However, unsure how to do this inside the pipe, or inside the req.pipe.

Jquery is working on Node.JS. But not sure how to pipe the contents retrieved through a jquery (or how to write one inside a pipe) to remove the tags   and all child nodes.

Comment: Have   you  tried cheerio?

Comment: Was hoping to do this inline using jquery to minimize the overhead. Jquery is used on the server for other things as well. Since the html is already available, it may be more efficient to use jquery instead of using cheerio or puppeteer?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `Jquery is used on the server`. Then don't you have code sample? Aren't you confusing it with `cheerio`, which uses the same syntax but is specifically meant for server-side? Also why doing it in the pipe? The operation you describe is global => it is meant to be run on the full HTML, not on a stream. So,  I would first do the `request(url)`, then the transformation using `cheerio`, then return the transformed version. No need to pipe.

Comment: Jquery is available on the server. Jquery is used for other details. I am trying to use Jquery to parse the html and transform the html. I am not using cheerio. I was replying to PeterKA. Doing it in a pipe to be more efficient and not store anything on the server. We have a lot of data hopping in and out. So we currently cannot afford to have html stored on the ec2 instance with multiple requests. So a pipe will help prevent us from accumulating too much data.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this kind of processing belongs in the server-side, as far as your setup is concerned.

Let's say you have the HTML string in a variable `html` then you can remove the `center` tags as follows:

```
const newHtml = $('<div/>').append(html).find('center').remove().end().html();
```

**DEMO**

```js
const $remote = $('<div/>').append($('#remote-content'));
console.log( $remote.html() );
const $nocenter = $remote.find('center').remove().end();
console.log( $nocenter.html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="remote-content">
  <h1>Sample Header</h1>
  <p>Sample paragraph</p>
  <center>
      <h2>Sample Sub-Header</h2>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </center>
  <em>On more line</em>
  <center>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </center>
</div>
```

**NOTE**

On the server-side, it would be very similar code but you'd be using `cheerio` instead of `jQuery`:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html); //html variable has the remote html string
$('center').remove();
const newHtml = $.html();
```